# Selecting ComboBox item freezes application

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-testing

I have a combo box item that if the user chooses it, it will reset some other values in the same UI. The application then displays a message box asking the user to confirm that the other values are changed. But the ComboBoxItem.Select() freezes the code execution so it is not possible to handle the message box that is displayed.

I'm using [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI) for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Select from the SelectionPattern waits until all actions are performed. Which means it waits until the messagebox is closed.
Try using Click instead.